# ndk build task not getting called when building project through command line

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, android-ndk

I have created following ndk task for building native component.

```
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir}

task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
println "hello 1"
commandLine 'ndk-path/ndk-build', 'NDK_PROJECT_PATH=project path'
println "hello 2"}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild}
```

Now when I call "./gradlew ndk-build" then .so is created under libs folder. But when I do "./gradlew assembleDebug" or "./gradlew build" then I get folowing outputs

```
hello 1
hello 2
```

But .so is not created. What is the problem?

Comment: try to insert the absolute path(s). If it works, you will know there's a problem with the paths. `pwd` prints the working directory under Linux.